# how to notify users about progress of a computation in flask python

Tags: python, flask, streaming, computation

I am serving some results of computation on flask.

For complex ones, it can takes time, and I would like to show a progress bar or something, informing the user the system is actually doing something and it is not freezed.

I can't estimate well how long it would take.

Conceptually, how could I implement a notification to user in flask, while a computation is being run ? Is it something similar to streaming data?

I know it sound generic, I am asking for things I should look at as suggestions to tackle the problem, or a scaffolding of pseudo code showing how a GET ajax from the front end would deal with flask response, that should notify that progress of a computation being run but not completed yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you describe is more a structural problem, not completely related to Flask. The backend, in this case Flask, provide an api, and on the client side you need to handle the results presentation properly, waiting time included.

Let's assume you implemented and exposed an API with Flask, you can handle the call from the frontend using javascript in the following way:

[running example](https://jsfiddle.net/205qebmj/1/)

```
# HTML
<div class="status" onclick="refresh()">click me</div>

# JAVASCRIPT
function refresh() {
  var status = document.querySelector('.status');
  status.textContent = "calling api";
  callAPI();

  function callAPI() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      // Flask API call here ...
      setTimeout(function(){ resolve()}, 2000);
    });
  }

  callAPI().then(function(result) {
    status.textContent =  "show results";
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi @Marco, thank u for your time. Im already doing something like that, my problem is that the call the to API launch a computation which can take a while. I wish to notify the user not only that has to wait (e.g. with a timer or smtg in front-end) but to provide an estimate of how long, based on the progress of the computation in the backend. You pointed out it could be a structural problem with a promise example - it might be a suggestion notify something by chaining promises (breaking down processing with multiple then() )  - wonder if there's an equivalent to "promise" API result in flask?